# Find the location of the Dock programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, dock

Is there a way in code to find out if the Dock on a Mac is located on the bottom, left, or right side of the user's monitor?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I am working on an app that will dock itself to the bottom or the side of the screen, but only if the current Mac dock isn't there already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSScreen` has `visibleFrame` method, wich returns a rect that doesn't include the area currently occupied by the dock and menu bar. You can compare this rect with the full screen rect(`- (NSRect) [NSScreen* frame]`) and determine the dock location.

Comment: Cool that is what I was originally thinking.  I was hoping there was some method that I didn't know of that would return it for me.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably simpler…

`defaults read com.apple.dock "orientation"`

> bottom

You can also find out.. `autohide` (i.e. 1), `large size` (i.e. "65.48148") and `magnification` (i.e. 1), etc.

Comment: How do I call "defaults read com.apple.dock orientation" from a cocoa app?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *dockParameterYouWant = [[defaults persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.dock"] valueForKey:@"thatParameterYouWant"];`

Comment: Thanks, this helps with a different issue of mine

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't mean to click it.  I'm still using the other answer currently.

Comment: does this also work for sandboxed apps? Also any idea on how to get the dock's size? Or a notification when the user hovered it (or an icon in it)?

Comment: i have no idea if you can access defaults in the sandbox... haven't been able to find a definitive answer anywhere.  if you do, let me know.

Comment: Note that when the dock's position hasn't been set yet, there could be no entry for "orientation". So remember to fall back to a default "bottom" value

Answer (score 2):

[private discovered API](http://undocumented-goodness.googlecode.com/svn-history/r15/trunk/CoreDock/CoreDockPrivate.h) used by prefs panel

```
typedef enum {
  kCoreDockOrientationTop = 1,
  kCoreDockOrientationBottom = 2,
  kCoreDockOrientationLeft = 3,
  kCoreDockOrientationRight = 4
} CoreDockOrientation;

extern void CoreDockGetOrientationAndPinning(CoreDockOrientation *outOrientation, CoreDockPinning *outPinning);
// If you only want to set one, use 0 for the other.
extern void CoreDockSetOrientationAndPinning(CoreDockOrientation orientation, CoreDockPinning pinning);
```